# how to draw a image inside Rectangular Figure in GEF editor

Tags: eclipse-gef

I have drawn one rectangle by using RectangleFigure in draw2d. Am able to setBackgroundColor,setForegroundColor....How i need to draw a image inside RectangleFigure.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Extend your figure from `org.eclipse.draw2d.ImageFigure` class.

In constructor you can pass `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image` which can be passed to super class.